# How to calculate area of the output of r.water.outlet?

Tags: python, grass-gis, watershed, grass.script

I wrote the following code to use `r.water.outlet` module in GRASS GIS:

```
import os
import sys

#set up GRASS environment variables
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['GISBASE'], 'etc', 'python'))
import grass.script as g
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE']
gisdb = 'C:\Users\Heinz\Documents\grassdata'
location = 'newLocation'
mapset = 'TC'
gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)

#csv file reading and importation
import csv
rows = list(open('tc_sta.csv'))
totalrows = len(rows) - 1

#loop through the csv(coordinates) file in r.water.outlet module
f = open('tc_sta.csv', 'r')
element = list(csv.reader(f))
i = 0
j = 0
while True:
    if i <= totalrows:
        g.run_command('r.water.outlet', drainage = 'dra', basin = 'b' + str(i + 1), east = element[i][j], north = element[i][j + 1])
        i = i + 1
    else:
        break

#print all files in grass database to check results of the module
print g.read_command('g.list', _type='rast')
```

I stored the coordinates in **tc_sta.csv**, and input them to `r.water.outlet` to calculate drainage area of each point.

Although the output raster files were fine, I had to export them as ESRI shapefile and use QGIS to calculate area of polygons, and finally store the area value of each point in a csv file containing coordinates and its related drainage area.

I felt that the procedure was not efficient, and is there a way I could calculate and store the output area immediately after I run `r.water.outlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [r.report](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.report.html) on the outlet map right away after the r.water.outlet step. It calculates the area size in a user defined unit (m^2, ha, etc.)

Comment: It's a nice advice! I am wondering if I use python to save the area value **r.report** outputs in a CSV file?

Comment: I tried r.stats and it also worked! Thank you for the advice, could you help me with this post, thanks? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215075/how-to-save-area-value-returned-by-r-stats-in-a-csv-file

Comment: Here is existing GRASS GIS Python code for parsing the r.report output: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass-addons/grass7/raster/r.green/libgreen/utils.py#L83 which you may use and adapt.

Comment: thank you, but how can I use this? I downloaded utils.py and put it in C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.0.5\scripts, but I still can't run `perc_of_overlay` in GRASS. And I still can not store just the area value.

Answer (score 1):

I routinely use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -lt 3  ]]; then
        echo "Parameters missing"
        exit 1
else
        BASIN=$1
        X=$2
        Y=$3
fi
g.region --q rast=<flow_dir>
r.stream.basins --o direction=<flow_dir> coordinates="${X},${Y}" basin=${BASIN}

r.to.vect --o -s $BASIN output=${BASIN} type=area
v.db.addcolumn $BASIN column="area_sqkm double"
v.db.update $BASIN column=label value=${BASIN}
v.to.db $BASIN option=area unit=kilometers column=area_sqkm
[[ -f ${BASIN}.shp ]] && rm -f ${BASIN}.*
v.out.ogr -s -e $BASIN output=${BASIN}.shp
```

Maybe it will be of some help.