# How to save area value returned by r.stats in a numpy array?

Tags: python, grass-gis

I want to write a python script to get and save basin area value of interested points on a drainage line from outside GRASS. I think the workflow could be:

1. run `r.watershed` and get drainage file
2. run `r.water.outlet` to get drainage area file of interested points
3. run `r.stats` to get area value of each interested point and save them in a CSV file

The python script for the first 2 stages ran well, and thus I wrote a python script **r_stats** trying to run GRASS GIS module `r.stats` from outside,

```
import os
import sys
from GRASSGIS_conn import GRASSGIS_conn


def r_stats(flag, map_name, sep):

    g.run_command('r.stats', flags = flag, input = map_name, separator = sep, output = 'dd.csv')


if __name__ == "__main__":


    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['GISBASE'], 'etc', 'python'))
    import grass.script as g
    gisdb = 'C:\Users\Heinz\Documents\grassdata'
    location = 'nl'
    mapset = 'nl'
    GRASSGIS_conn(gisdb, location, mapset)
    map_name = 'b1'
    flag = 'na'
    sep = 'comma'
    r_stats(flag, map_name, sep)
```

The resulting CSV file contains a category column and another area value column although I just want area value. Now the problem is that because I need to get area values of more than one raster files loaded in GRASS GIS, and the code above would output too many CSV files and it's inefficient to re-organize them.

Is there a way to store these area value in a numpy array? Or are there better way to get and save area value than `r.stats`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited my code based on @Stefan B.'s idea:

```
def r_stats(flag, map_name, sep):

    res = g.read_command('r.stats', flags = flag, input = map_name, separator = sep)
    nres = numpy.array(float(res[2:]))
    print nres
```

it outputs just area value in numpy array form.

Answer (score 3):

grass.read_command (g.read_command('r.stats'...) instead of g.run_command('r.stats' ...))
grass.read_command "reads the data from the command's stdout, and returns it as a string"
See: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library#Uses_for_read.2C_feed_and_pipe.2C_start_and_exec_commands